# How is this Nested Set SQL query converted into a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Querying a [Nested Set Model table](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), here's the SQL... how can this be written in LINQ?

```
SELECT parent.name
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND node.name = 'FLASH'
ORDER BY parent.lft;
```

particularly, the FROM part... never tried to do anything like that in LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
var query = from node in nested_category
            from parentNode in nested_category
            where node.lft >= parentNode.lft && node.rgt <= parentNode.rgt
                 && node.name == "FLASH"
            orderby parent.left
            select parent.name;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some testing. At a glance, looks good. Don't know why I didn't think to just have 2 from statements. :D

Answer (score 1):

if you do the LEFT OUTER join like that (that is without using ***into*** and ***DefaultIfEmpty()***) then the top-level parent node will not be output (because it's parent is NULL)

My SQL version which goes:

```
SELECT 
    B.ELEMENT_CODE ParentElement,
    A.ELEMENT_CODE ChildElement
FROM NESTED_SET_STRUCTURE AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN NESTED_SET_STRUCTURE AS B
  ON B.PROCEDURE = 'TEST1' AND B.FROM_LEFT = (SELECT MAX(C.FROM_LEFT)
             FROM NESTED_SET_STRUCTURE AS C
             WHERE C.PROCEDURE = 'TEST1' AND A.FROM_LEFT > C.FROM_LEFT
               AND A.FROM_LEFT < C.TO_RIGHT)
WHERE
    A.PROCEDURE = 'TEST1';
```

Translates as:

```
var nestedSets1 = 
    from a in NESTED_SET_STRUCTUREs
    join b in NESTED_SET_STRUCTUREs on 
    new { a.PROCEDURE, FROM_LEFT = ((from c in NESTED_SET_STRUCTUREs 
        where c.PROCEDURE.Equals("TEST1") 
        && a.FROM_LEFT > c.FROM_LEFT 
        && a.FROM_LEFT < c.TO_RIGHT
        select (c.FROM_LEFT)).Max()) } equals 
    new { b.PROCEDURE, b.FROM_LEFT } into bo
    from bb in bo.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where
        a.PROCEDURE.Equals("TEST1") 
    orderby a.FROM_LEFT
    select new {
        ParentElement = bb.ELEMENT_CODE,
        ChildElement = a.ELEMENT_CODE
    };
```

Hope that helps, Paul.